# displaying Contact and Phone numbers in a check box

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contactscontract

I tried this code to display the phone numbers in a checkbox within a listView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main1);
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);

   Cursor numberCursor = null;
   Cursor peopleCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract
        .Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null
           ,null,null);  

   String [] nb = null ;
   String [] Tname = null;

   if(peopleCursor.getCount()>0)
   {  
       peopleCursor.moveToFirst();

       for(int i=0;i<peopleCursor.getCount();i++)
       {  
           //get number
           numberCursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract
                .CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}
                ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"="+peopleCursor
                .getString(peopleCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)),  
                null,null);
           numberCursor.moveToFirst(); 

           String number=numberCursor.getString(numberCursor 
                  .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
           nb[i]=number;

           //get name
           String name=peopleCursor.getString(numberCursor
               .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
           Tname[i]=name;

           peopleCursor.moveToNext();                   
       }   

       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,  
           R.layout.contact_entry, numberCursor,nb, 
           new int[] {R.id.checkBox});

           lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

But I get this error in the logcat and I don't understand it --->

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should define size of nb and Tname before use them:

```
      String[] Tname  = new String[peopleCursor.getCount()];

      String[] nb = new String[numberCursor.getCount()];
```

But i think the problems is with **each people** in your contacts list may **have one or more phone numbers**.
So, You should have two loops for `peopleCursor` and `numberCursor`. and your index (`i` in your code) should be used only for array `Tname`.

Comment: yes i define the size of nb and Tname but always the same error ----> "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0"